# Running init_db() in the console won't work

Tags: python, flask

Whenever I try to import init db in the python console:

```
>>from app.database import init_db
>>init_db()
init db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "app\database.py", line 18, in init_db
    import models
ImportError: No module named models
```

This is the content of my app.database function:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    print "init db"
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Why is it like this?

UPDATE: This is the structure of my project.

```
app/
   filebase/
      init.py
      models.py
   users/
      init.py
      models.py
   projects/
      init.py
      models.py
init.py
database.py (this is where the init_db was defined
```

As for the structure on why it looked like that, the reason is to make the project modular in its form.

Answer (score 0):

You need the parent directory of `models.py` (or, of the `models` package) to be in your `sys.path`.  You can put it there in your console session, or, in the shell, add it to environment variable `PYTHON_PATH` so it will be set at entry to the console session.

Comment: How do I do this then? I'm very sorry since I'm just new on operating flask.

Comment: Where does your `models.py` (or `models` package) live?  If it lives in `/foo/bar`, then at the interpreter prompt do `import sys` and then `sys.path.append('/foo/bar')`.  This way, the `import models` will work (though of course this can't guarantee some **other** imports won't later, it depends on what you're importing where, and the secret you don't tell us, what's your directory structure!-)